# Sonar-run client path error

Tags: java, path, sonarqube

SONAR newbie roadblock:

1. I just installed SONAR on windows XP. Was able to configure it as a service and get the server running.
2. Then I installed sonar-runner (in a directory named `sonar-run`), created a `sonar-project.properties` in root, and configured it to point to my Java src project at **C:\sonar-run\src**.
3. Tried running from my Java project src directory - C:\sonar-run\src>`..\bin\sonar-runner`

First it failed with the message

```
Unable to resolve path '"C:sonar-runsrc"'
```

so I escaped the path with extra backslashes **`"C:\\sonar-run\\src"`**, then I am stuck at this error:

```
C:\sonar-run\src>..\bin\sonar-runner
C:\sonar-run
Runner configuration file: C:\sonar-run\conf\sonar-runner.properties
Project configuration file: C:\sonar-run\src\sonar-project.properties
Runner version: 1.3
...
...

Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to resolve path '"C:\sonar-run\src"'
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:189)          
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: 
Unable to resolve path **'"C:\sonar-run\src"'**
```

---

**What I think is the error :** something to do with Unix/Windows/path/escape sequence.

Observation : earlier I was using **C:\runsonar** as the folder name and it was escaping \r as a special character.

---

**CONCLUSION: Though this is a localized error I faced, these are the learnings for SONAR newbies:**

1. When you are sonar-runner as the client program , you need to understand SONAR was designed for *nix, so how it behaves in Windows is different and not clearly documented
2. In the properties file> windows path for src > you need to escape the **`\`**
3. If you path contains a folder starting with **`r`**. e.g `\src\red` then even after escaping like `src\\red` it will become `src` `\r` `ed` which means a `return` character, so on for `\n` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **remove the double quotes** in the properties file
The error message says 
   Unable to resolve path '**"**C:\sonar-run\src***"*'

Your entry should look like
C:\sonar-run\src